# `npm list -g` does not list any modules

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to list my global packages with `npm list -g`, but I get no modules in the output. I can manually view all of my global modules in my filesystem via `ls ~/npm/lib/node_modules/`, and `npm prefix -g` is set to `~/npm/lib`. Interestingly, `sudo npm list -g` only shows my modules under `~/.nvm/v6.2.0/lib/node_modules` which is just the "npm" module. How can I show all of my global modules with `npm list -g`?

Here is an example of the output that I am getting:

```
[my-pc]/home/folder$ npm root -g -ddd
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/home/me/.nvm/v6.2.0/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/home/me/npm/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'ls',
npm verb cli   '-g',
npm verb cli   '-ddd' ]
npm info using npm@3.9.2
npm info using node@v6.2.0
/home/me/npm/lib/node_modules
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm info ok

[my-pc]/home/folder$ npm prefix -g -ddd
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/home/me/.nvm/v6.2.0/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/home/me/npm/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'prefix',
npm verb cli   '-g',
npm verb cli   '-ddd' ]
npm info using npm@3.9.2
npm info using node@v6.2.0
/home/me/npm
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm info ok


[my-pc]/home/.../folder$ sudo npm ls -g --depth=0

/home/me/.nvm/v6.2.0/lib

└── npm@3.9.3

[my-pc]/home/.../folder$ npm ls -g --depth=0
<no output>

[my-pc]/home/.../folder$ sudo npm outdated -g --depth=0

Package  Current  Wanted  Latest  Location

npm        3.9.3   3.9.3   3.9.2
up

[my-pc]/home/.../folder$ ll ~/.nvm/v6.2.0/lib/node_modules/
total 12

drwxr-xr-x  3 me  me 4096 May 23 15:31 ./
drwxr-xr-x  3 me  me 4096 May 17 12:40 ../
drwxr-xr-x 12 nobody me 4096 May 23 15:31 npm/


[my-pc]/home/.../folder$ ll ~/npm/lib/node_modules/
total 92
drwxrwxr-x 20 me me 4096 May 23 15:39 ./
drwxrwxr-x  3 me me 4096 Feb 17  2015 ../
drwxr-xr-x  4 me me 4096 Apr 18 00:43 bower/
drwxr-xr-x  5 me me 4096 Apr 17 12:12 dat/
drwxr-xr-x  6 me me 4096 Jun 18  2015 grunt-cli/
drwxr-xr-x  6 me me 4096 Jun 25  2015 gulp/
drwxr-xr-x  9 me me 4096 Dec  5 03:08 jaws-framework/
drwxr-xr-x 10 me me 4096 May 18 13:38 learnyounode/
drwxr-xr-x  7 me me 4096 May 18 01:36 mapshaper/
drwxr-xr-x  6 me me 4096 Nov  6  2015 modulus/
drwxr-xr-x  8 me me 4096 Apr  6  2015 node-inspector/
drwxr-xr-x  5 me me 4096 Mar  9 15:51 node-rest-client/
drwxr-xr-x 11 me me 4096 May 23 15:39 npm/
drwxrwxr-x  5 me me 4096 Feb 17  2015 nvm/
drwxr-xr-x  3 me me 4096 May 25  2015 package-info/
drwxr-xr-x  3 me me 4096 Sep 16  2015 peerflix/
drwxr-xr-x  9 me me 4096 May 18 11:02 scope-chains-closures/
drwxr-xr-x  8 me me 4096 May 23 15:23 serverless/
drwxr-xr-x  6 me me 4096 Apr  7  2015 stream-adventure/
drwxr-xr-x  3 me me 4096 Apr 28  2015 superlevel/
```

As shown above, I am using NVM for my node version manager, which might be causing this confusion. But how can I make `npm list -g` properly list my globally installed packages?

BTW, my locally installed packages listed fine with `npm list`.

Comment: I'd avoid using `sudo` unless strictly necessary. It shouldn't be needed in this case.

Comment: Interestingly, if I don't use `sudo` and run `npm ls -g`, then I get no modules in the output. Note that when I use `sudo` above, with `sudo npm ls -g`, I get the "npm" module only.

Comment: The [`prefix` setting](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#prefix) has apparently been altered on your system. It was previously `~/npm/` and is now likely `/usr/local`. You can review it with [`npm prefix -g`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prefix) or [`npm config get prefix`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thanks for the tip. I just tested it, and the output for `npm prefix -g` is `/home/me/npm`, which agrees with the output of `ls ~/npm/lib/node_modules` listed above. BTW I updated my question with the output of the `npm prefix -g` test. But I still don't know why `npm ls -g` is empty because my global modules are clearly saved under `~/npm/lib/node_modules`

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue recently with Node v10 and npm v6.

```
npm list -g
```

returned

```
-- (empty)
```

The issue was Node environment was in production. Use this command to check:

```
echo $NODE_ENV
```

Mine was in **production**.

I changed it to **development** and it worked.

```
export NODE_ENV=development
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, echo $NODE_ENV returns blank, but when i `nano ~/.npmrc` it list:

```
production=true
env=production
```

I deleted both of them and re-run `npm list -g` and voila!